# Advanced search and replace

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, query-replace

I have a file, with a lot of instances of

```
...
fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
fclose(f3);
...
```

I'd like to replace these with

```
...
if(fclose(f1)!=0) return 1;
if(fclose(f2)!=0) return 1;
if(fclose(f3)!=0) return 1;
...
```

But, other than doing two separate search-and-replace, i haven't found a way to do this, which preserves the argument.
I think the regex version of search-and-replace may be able to do this, but I'm not nearly proficient at regexes to know how.

Comment: Just use a keyboard macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that [`query-replace-regex`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>) can do this. For the regular expression, you want `\(fclose(f.)\);` and your "to-string" you want `if(\1!=0) return 1;`

In the regular expression we create a group with `\(` and `\)`. That group consists of `fclose(f.)`. The `.` represents "any character".

The "to-string" contains `\1` This is a *backreference* to the first (only in this case) group, and on output is replaced by that match.

You can find more information on regular expressions in the [GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html), the [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html), and on the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression).